# Type 'Promise<(string[] | undefined)[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Etablissement[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, promise

.
Hello, with the help of the following code, I try to retrieve a table of "Etablissement" via asynchronous queries. The last line is underlined in red with this message:

`Type 'Promise<(string[] | undefined)[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Establishment[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.`

If anyone has an idea, any suggestions for resolution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is a code snippet :

```
interface GetApplicationHook {
    getApplication: (id?: string) => Promise<ApplicationToSave>
    defaultApplication: ApplicationToSave
    getOneEtablissement: (uai?: string) => Promise<Etablissement>
    toEtablissementsList: (ouList: string[]) => Etablissement[]
}
[...]
const getOneEtablissement = (uai?: string): Promise<Etablissement> => {
        if (uai) {
            return loadOneEtablissement(uai)
                .then((etab: Etablissement) => {
                    return {
                        nom: etab.nom,
                        uai: etab.uai,
                        ou: etab.ou,
                        description: etab.description,
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => Promise.reject("Erreur à la récupération de l'établissement=" + uai))
        }
        return Promise.resolve(defaultEtablissement)
    }

    const fromOuToUai = (ou: string): string => {
        try {
            return ou.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
        } catch (error) {
            return ou
        }
    }

    const toEtablissementsList = (ouList: string[]): Etablissement[] => {
        const etabList = Promise.all(
            ouList.map(ou => {
                try {
                    const uai = fromOuToUai(ou)
                    getOneEtablissement(uai)
                        .then((data: Etablissement) => data)
                        .catch(() => Promise.reject())
                } catch (error) {
                    return ouList
                }
            })
        )
        return etabList
    }

[...]
```

I have been looking for information about how `Promises` work and how to extract the interesting data from them. If I understood correctly, this should be done through the .then() method along with the .catch() method... but that doesn't seem to be enough here. The problem is about typing apparently but I don't see where the problem lies.

Comment: `.then((data: Etablissement) => data).catch(() => Promise.reject())` makes no sense

Comment: You're already using `Promise.all`, what you forgot is to `return` the `etOneEtablissement(uai)` promise from the `map` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the last line of your code is that `etabList` is a Promise that resolves to an array of `Etablissement[]`, not an array of Etablissement objects. This is because `Promise.all()` returns a promise that resolves to an array of the resolved values of the input promises.

You need to modify your `toEtablissementsList()` function to await the resolution of the `Promise.all()` call and then return the resulting `Etablissement[]` array. You can also simplify your code by removing the unnecessary try-catch blocks.

Something like this:

```
const toEtablissementsList = async (ouList: string[]): Promise<Etablissement[]> => {
  const etabListPromises = ouList.map(ou => {
    const uai = fromOuToUai(ou);
    return getOneEtablissement(uai);
  });

  const etabList = await Promise.all(etabListPromises);
  return etabList;
}
```

you can create an array of `Promise<Etablissement>` objects by mapping over the `ouList` array and calling `getOneEtablissement(`) for each `uai`. Then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises to resolve, and return the resulting `Etablissement[]` array.

Also changed the return type of `toEtablissementsList()` to `Promise<Etablissement[]>`, since the function is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`.

***Edit for request:***
*To extract an Etablissement[] from a Promise<Etablissement[]>, you need to wait for the promise to resolve using the await keyword or using the then() method.*

```
function getEtablissementsList() {
  const ouList = ["ou1", "ou2", "ou3"];
  const etabListPromise = toEtablissementsList(ouList);
  etabListPromise.then(etabList => {
    console.log(etabList); // do something with the Etablissement[] array
  });
}

getEtablissementsList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The same as for Michel Novellino, this function should be used to return a list of Etablissement (and not a Promise). Could you please tell me how to extract an Etablissement[] from the Promise<Establishment[]> ?

Comment: To extract an `Etablissement[]` from a `Promise<Etablissement[]>`, you need to wait for the promise to resolve using the `await` keyword or using the `then()` method. I'll add it in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code is that the toEtablissementsList function is returning a Promise instead of an array of Etablissement objects.

try this:

```
const toEtablissementsList = (ouList: string[]): Promise<Etablissement[]> => {
  return Promise.all(
    ouList.map((ou) => {
      try {
        const uai = fromOuToUai(ou);
        return getOneEtablissement(uai);
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    })
  ).then((etabList) => etabList.filter((etab) => !!etab));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact this function should be used to return a list of Etablissement. Could you please tell me how to extract an Etablissement[] from the Promise<Establishment[]> ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the full component code, if this can help (the attribute listeOrganisations at the bottom needs to be a Etablissement[]) :

```
import ApplicationRole from 'domain/ApplicationRole'
import ApplicationProfile from 'domain/ApplicationProfile'
import ApplicationToSave from 'domain/ApplicationToSave'
import useAppsToutaticeService from 'service/AppsToutaticeService'
import TimeUtils from './TimeUtils'
import Etablissement from 'domain/Etablissement'
import useEtablissementService from 'service/EtablissementService'

interface GetApplicationHook {
    getApplication: (id?: string) => Promise<ApplicationToSave>
    defaultApplication: ApplicationToSave
    getOneEtablissement: (uai?: string) => Promise<Etablissement>
    toEtablissementsList: (ouList: string[]) => Etablissement[]
}

const GetApplication = (): GetApplicationHook => {
    const { loadApp } = useAppsService()
    const { loadOneEtablissement } = useEtablissementService()

    const defaultApplication = {
        applicationId: '',
        nom: '',
        description: '',
        categorie: ' ',
        dateFermeture: '',
        dateOuverture: '',
        icone: '',
        statut: '',
        urlConnexion: '',
        urlDeconnexion: '',
        dnmaTypeService: '',
        dnmaCategorie: ' ',
        dnmaUai: '',
        dnmaOutil: ' ',
        listeManagers: [],
        listeExplicitManagers: [],
        listeExplicitMembers: [],
        listeOrganisations: [],
        listeProfils: [],
        listeRoles: [],
    }

    const defaultEtablissement = {
        nom: '',
        uai: '',
        ou: '',
        description: '',
    }

    const getFirstElementOrDefault = (elements?: string[], defaultValue = '') => {
        if (elements && elements.length > 0) return elements[0]
        return defaultValue
    }

    const toApplicationProfile = (profile: string): ApplicationProfile => {
        return {
            dn: profile,
            cn: profile.split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
        }
    }

    const toApplicationProfileList = (profileList: string[]): ApplicationProfile[] => {
        if (profileList && profileList.length > 0) {
            return profileList.map(profile => toApplicationProfile(profile))
        }
        return []
    }

    const toApplicationRole = (appRole: string): ApplicationRole => {
        return {
            cn: appRole.split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
            dn: appRole,
            nom: '',
            description: '',
            listeProfils: [],
            listeProprietaires: [],
            listeManagers: [],
            listeExplicitManagers: [],
            listeTags: [],
            listeMemberUrl: [],
        }
    }

    const toApplicationRoleList = (appRolesList: string[]): ApplicationRole[] => {
        if (appRolesList && appRolesList.length > 0) {
            return appRolesList.map(appRole => toApplicationRole(appRole))
        }
        return []
    }

    const { isoToDate } = TimeUtils()

    const getOneEtablissement = (uai?: string): Promise<Etablissement> => {
        if (uai) {
            return loadOneEtablissement(uai)
                .then((etab: Etablissement) => {
                    return {
                        nom: etab.nom,
                        uai: etab.uai,
                        ou: etab.ou,
                        description: etab.description,
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => Promise.reject("Erreur à la récupération de l'établissement=" + uai))
        }
        return Promise.resolve(defaultEtablissement)
    }

    const fromOuToUai = (ou: string): string => {
        try {
            return ou.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
        } catch (error) {
            return ou
        }
    }

    const toEtablissementsList = (ouList: string[]): Etablissement[] => {
        const etabList = Promise.all(
            ouList.map(ou => {
                try {
                    const uai = fromOuToUai(ou)
                    getOneEtablissement(uai)
                        .then((data: Etablissement) => data)
                        .catch(() => Promise.reject())
                } catch (error) {
                    return ouList
                }
            })
        )
        return etabList
    }

    const getApplication = (id?: string): Promise<ApplicationToSave> => {
        if (id) {
            return loadApp(id)
                .then(app => {
                    return {
                        applicationId: app.applicationId,
                        description: app.description,
                        nom: app.nom,
                        categorie: getFirstElementOrDefault(app.listeCategories, ' ').toLocaleLowerCase(),
                        dateFermeture: isoToDate(app.endTime),
                        dateOuverture: isoToDate(app.startTime),
                        icone: app.icone ?? '',
                        statut: app.statut ?? 'TITI',
                        urlConnexion: app.url ?? '',
                        urlDeconnexion: getFirstElementOrDefault(app.listeUrlLogout),
                        dnmaTypeService: app.dnmaTypeService ?? 'TOTO',
                        dnmaCategorie: app.dnmaCatego ?? ' ',
                        dnmaUai: app.dnmaRne ?? 'TUTU',
                        dnmaOutil: app.dnmaOutil ?? ' ',
                        listeManagers: [],
                        listeExplicitMembers: [],
                        listeExplicitManagers: [],
                        listeOrganisations: toEtablissementsList(app.listeOrganisations),
                        listeProfils: toApplicationProfileList(app.listeProfils),
                        listeRoles: toApplicationRoleList(app.listeRoles),
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => Promise.reject("Erreur à la récupération de l'application=" + id))
        }
        return Promise.resolve(defaultApplication)
    }
    return { getApplication, defaultApplication, getOneEtablissement, toEtablissementsList }
}

export default GetApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for all your answers,

I finally used the function suggested by Benji after which I made some other modifications in my code. Here is the final result if it can help anyone.

Good day to you !

````
    import ApplicationRole from 'domain/ApplicationRole'
    import ApplicationProfile from 'domain/ApplicationProfile'
    import ApplicationToSave from 'domain/ApplicationToSave'
    import useAppsToutaticeService from 'service/AppsToutaticeService'
    import TimeUtils from './TimeUtils'
    import Etablissement from 'domain/Etablissement'
    import useEtablissementService from 'service/EtablissementService'
    import ApplicationToutatice from 'domain/ApplicationToutatice'
    
    interface GetApplicationHook {
        getApplication: (id?: string) => Promise<ApplicationToSave>
        defaultApplication: ApplicationToSave
    }
    
    const GetApplication = (): GetApplicationHook => {
        const { loadApp } = useAppsToutaticeService()
        const { loadOneEtablissement } = useEtablissementService()
    
        const defaultApplication = {
            applicationId: '',
            nom: '',
            description: '',
            categorie: ' ',
            dateFermeture: '',
            dateOuverture: '',
            icone: '',
            statut: '',
            urlConnexion: '',
            urlDeconnexion: '',
            dnmaTypeService: '',
            dnmaCategorie: ' ',
            dnmaUai: '',
            dnmaOutil: ' ',
            listeManagers: [],
            listeExplicitManagers: [],
            listeExplicitMembers: [],
            listeOrganisations: [],
            listeProfils: [],
            listeRoles: [],
        }
    
        const getFirstElementOrDefault = (elements?: string[], defaultValue = '') => {
            if (elements && elements.length > 0) return elements[0]
            return defaultValue
        }
    
        const toApplicationProfile = (profile: string): ApplicationProfile => {
            return {
                dn: profile,
                cn: profile.split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
            }
        }
    
        const toApplicationProfileList = (profileList: string[]): ApplicationProfile[] => {
            if (profileList && profileList.length > 0) {
                return profileList.map(profile => toApplicationProfile(profile))
            }
            return []
        }
    
        const toApplicationRole = (appRole: string): ApplicationRole => {
            return {
                cn: appRole.split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
                dn: appRole,
                nom: '',
                description: '',
                listeProfils: [],
                listeProprietaires: [],
                listeManagers: [],
                listeExplicitManagers: [],
                listeTags: [],
                listeMemberUrl: [],
            }
        }
    
        const toApplicationRoleList = (appRolesList: string[]): ApplicationRole[] => {
            if (appRolesList && appRolesList.length > 0) {
                return appRolesList.map(appRole => toApplicationRole(appRole))
            }
            return []
        }
    
        const { isoToDate } = TimeUtils()
    
        const defaultEtablissement = {
            nom: '',
            uai: '',
            ou: '',
            description: '',
        }
    
        const getOneEtablissement = (uai?: string): Promise<Etablissement> => {
            if (uai) {
                return loadOneEtablissement(uai)
                    .then((etab: Etablissement) => {
                        return {
                            nom: etab.nom,
                            uai: etab.uai,
                            ou: etab.ou,
                            description: etab.description,
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(() => Promise.reject("Erreur à la récupération de l'établissement=" + uai))
            }
            return Promise.resolve(defaultEtablissement)
        }
    
        const fromOuToUai = (ou: string): string => {
            try {
                return ou.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
            } catch (error) {
                return ou
            }
        }
    
        const toEtablissementsList = async (ouList: string[]): Promise<Etablissement[]> => {
            const etabListPromises = ouList.map(ou => {
                const uai = fromOuToUai(ou)
                return getOneEtablissement(uai)
            })
    
            const etabList = await Promise.all(etabListPromises)
            return etabList
        }
    
        const toApplicationToSave = (app: ApplicationToutatice, etabListAsOu: string[]): Promise<ApplicationToSave> => {
            return toEtablissementsList(etabListAsOu)
                .then(etabList => {
                    return {
                        applicationId: app.applicationId,
                        description: app.description,
                        nom: app.nom,
                        categorie: getFirstElementOrDefault(app.listeCategories, ' ').toLocaleLowerCase(),
                        dateFermeture: isoToDate(app.endTime),
                        dateOuverture: isoToDate(app.startTime),
                        icone: app.icone ?? '',
                        statut: app.statut ?? 'TOTO',
                        urlConnexion: app.url ?? '',
                        urlDeconnexion: getFirstElementOrDefault(app.listeUrlLogout),
                        dnmaTypeService: app.dnmaTypeService ?? 'TITI',
                        dnmaCategorie: app.dnmaCatego ?? ' ',
                        dnmaUai: app.dnmaRne ?? 'TUTU',
                        dnmaOutil: app.dnmaOutil ?? ' ',
                        listeManagers: [],
                        listeExplicitMembers: [],
                        listeExplicitManagers: [],
                        listeOrganisations: etabList,
                        listeProfils: toApplicationProfileList(app.listeProfils),
                        listeRoles: toApplicationRoleList(app.listeRoles),
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => Promise.reject())
        }
    
        const getApplication = (id?: string): Promise<ApplicationToSave> => {
            if (id) {
                return loadApp(id)
                    .then(app => {
                        return toApplicationToSave(app, app.listeOrganisations)
                    })
                    .catch(() => Promise.reject("Erreur à la récupération de l'application=" + id))
            }
            return Promise.resolve(defaultApplication)
        }
    
        return { getApplication, defaultApplication }
    }
    
    export default GetApplication```
````

Comment: I'm happy that you managed to make it work. Great job!